# Having trouble adding every other odd element in a list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I'm trying to add all the odd elements in the list.

I can't figure out what is wrong. It will work for a list of all odds, but causes an error if there is even a single even number -- it says  that it expected a number as the second element but instead a list was passed in, which shouldn't be happening.

What is wrong with my code?

```
(define list-sum-odd
  (lambda (list)
    (cond
      ((null? list)
       0)
      ((odd? (car list))
       (+ (car list) (list-sum-odd (cdr list))))
      (list-sum-odd 
       (cdr list)))))
```

Comment: I've edited the formatting of the code so that the question and answer  are on separate lines.  It should make it easier to see that, as far as the language knows, `list-sum-odd` is meant to be the question, and `(cdr list)` is the answer.  But as we know, that's not the intent the OP wants.  Retief's answer applies.

Answer (score 6):

Replace `(list-sum-odd (cdr list))` with `(else (list-sum-odd (cdr list)))`.  As is, you are testing whether the procedure `list-sum-odd` is true (since it is not #f, it is), and then returning `(cdr list)`.  You need to tell Scheme that the last expression is supposed to be the `else` expression.